# I saw this recursion template in XSLT and cannot understand what is happening

Tags: xslt, recursion

What happens when the control gets into xsl:variable? It should never reach `<xsl:value-of select="$number * $recursive_result"/>` as it is calling the template again and again but it does. This made me question the overall control flow of XSLT. Please explain!

```
<xsl:template name="factorial">
  <xsl:param name="number" select="1"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$number &lt; 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="recursive_result">
        <xsl:call-template name="factorial">
          <xsl:with-param name="number" select="$number - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$number * $recursive_result"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Each time you recursively call the template, you decrease the actual value of the `number`.You have an `<xsl:when>` that "returns" 1 when your param named `number` reaches 0. This ends the recursive calls.

Comment: @potame : I understand that the actual value is decreased with each call. What I am not able to understand is, when does the control reaches at $number * $recursive_result and what will be the value in $recursive_result the first time it executes? From what I can see, the control will never come out of the xsl:variable tag and xsl:when will be satisfied. How does this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does reach the `<xsl:value-of select="$number * $recursive_result"/>`.

If you look at the variable declaration:

```
<xsl:variable name="recursive_result">
<xsl:call-template name="factorial">
    <xsl:with-param name="number" select="$number - 1"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Every time the template, factorial, is called, the parameter being passed is reduced by 1(look at the following instruction):

```
<xsl:with-param name="number" select="$number - 1"/>
```

So, for example, if the template `factorial` was called, at first, with value of `3`,
the `<xsl:otherwise>` is reached and the variable in the `factorial` template's `<xsl:otherwise>` makes a call to `factorial` template again but this time with value as 2. And similarly with 1, and then with 0.
When called with `0` as the value, the `<xsl:when>` is entered and the output 1 is produced for that instance of recursive call. Then the control returns to where the template was called from(the previous instance of `factorial` call). And hence, the `<xsl:value-of>` being the next intruction is called.

This happens to all the previous instances of `factorial` calls that called the template recursively(and hence processing `<xsl:value-of>` of every `<xsl:otherwise>` as being the next instruction after `<xsl:variable>`).

By the way, you can save 1 redundant call to the template by changing your `<xsl:when>` to:

```
<xsl:when test="$number &lt;= 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
</xsl:when>
```

To have a look at the variables/values at every call use this XSLT, which has `<xsl:message>` that prints specific values:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="factorial">
            <xsl:with-param name="number" select="5"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="iteration" select="1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="factorial">
    <xsl:param name="number" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="iteration" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$number &lt; 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="recursive_result">
                <xsl:call-template name="factorial">
                    <xsl:with-param name="number" select="$number - 1"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="iteration" select="$iteration + 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:message>iteration number = <xsl:value-of select="$iteration"/>; recursive_result = <xsl:value-of select="$recursive_result"/>; result = <xsl:value-of select="$number * $recursive_result"/> </xsl:message>
            <xsl:value-of select="$number * $recursive_result"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The number for which factorial is desired can by modified by modifying the following instruction in the first template:

```
<xsl:with-param name="number" select="5"/>
```

Here is the screenshot of what you can expect(using command line interface, depending on the processor you are using):

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation for recursion loop, +1.

Comment: @Lingamurthy : So, what would be the value in `$recursive_result` the first time it gets multiplied with `$n`? We never initialized `$recursive_result`. Also, I am starting to get the picture but, could you give me a stack representation of the function calls? My brain hurts trying to comprehend this. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: The first `$recursive_result` will have the value of all recursive calls to `factorial`. That is, `1 * 1 * 2`.. Let me try some way better to explain this..

Comment: Damn! I understood now. Your last comment. So, the first value in `$recursive_result` will have a value of 1(the `xsl:when`) and then it will continue with the last recursive call and execute `$number * $recursive_result` as (1 * 1), then (1 * 2), then (2 * 3). Please confirm my understanding!

Comment: You got it almost right.. The value `1` is for the last recursive call(not the first, as you mentioned in your comment). I've edited my answer. I hope it helps.