# XSLT Recursion and variables

Tags: xml, variables, recursion, xslt, factorial

```
<xsl:template name="factorial">
  <xsl:param name="number" select="1"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$number &lt; 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="recursive_result">
        <xsl:call-template name="factorial">
          <xsl:with-param name="number" select="$number - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$number * $recursive_result"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

[I saw this recursion template in XSLT and cannot understand what is happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634960/i-saw-this-recursion-template-in-xslt-and-cannot-understand-what-is-happening)

Dear Lingamurthy,

I read what you wrote on this page and I find it difficult to understand recursion with variables.
*So, for example, if the template factorial was called, at first, with value of 3, the  is reached and the variable in the factorial template's  makes a call to factorial template again but this time with value as 2. And similarly with 1, and then with 0. When called with 0 as the value, the  is entered and the output 1 is produced for that instance of recursive call. Then the control returns to where the template was called from(the previous instance of factorial call). And hence, the  being the next intruction is called.*

How can the processor multiply , ie 1 * 1 * 2, since the $number and the $recursive_result have been reduced to 1 in the last call ? How can he retrieve the values ?

Could you help me ?

Rodolphe

Answer (score 0):

The way recursive functions typically work is by building up a call stack. XSLT works similarly when recursive templates. Each invocation in the stack holds its own distinct copy of the parameters and variables.

```
factorial(3): number = 3, recursive_result = factorial(2), result = number * recursive_result
  factorial(2): number = 2, recursive_result = factorial(1), result = number * recursive_result
    factorial(1): number = 1, result = 1
```

Once `factorial(1)` returns its result of 1, we pop that off the stack and go to the next item, and everything reduces down as follows:

```
factorial(3): number = 3, recursive_result = factorial(2), result = number * recursive_result
  factorial(2): number = 2, recursive_result = 1, result = number * recursive_result
```

```
factorial(3): number = 3, recursive_result = factorial(2), result = number * recursive_result
  factorial(2): number = 2, recursive_result = 1, result = 2 * 1
```

```
factorial(3): number = 3, recursive_result = factorial(2), result = number * recursive_result
  factorial(2): number = 2, recursive_result = 1, result = 2
```

```
factorial(3): number = 3, recursive_result = 2, result = number * recursive_result
```

```
factorial(3): number = 3, recursive_result = 2, result = 3 * 2
```

```
factorial(3) = 6
```